# Trying to Get a new ServerSocket to open fails

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I was given the below code by my teacher for a class. I ran it one or twice and it worked fine. However I suddenly cannot get it to run from the command prompt on Windows 8 anymore. No matter what port I specify it just prints "Opening port..." and never continues. No exception is ever thrown. I have disabled my firewall and antivirus and it does not seem to work. I have added a print statement as the first line of the try catch block and it will print but it just will not create the new Socket. I am sure it is something in my Windows settings but I am unsure as to what or how to resolve it.

```
// Server program
// File name: "TCPServer.java"

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class TCPServer
{
     private static ServerSocket servSock;
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Opening port...\n");
        try{

       // Create a server object 
              servSock = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); 
        }

        catch(IOException e){
             System.out.println("Unable to attach to port!");
             System.exit(1);
        }

       do 
       {  
            run();
       }while (true);

    }

    private static void run()
   {
        Socket link = null; 
        try{



        // Put the server into a waiting state
               link = servSock.accept(); 

        // Set up input and output streams for socket
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream())); 
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true);

    // print local host name
              String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
              System.out.println("Client has estabished a connection to " + host);

    // Receive and process the incoming data 
             int numMessages = 0;
             String message = in.readLine(); 
             while (!message.equals("DONE"))
             {
                 System.out.println(message);
                 numMessages ++;
                 message = in.readLine();
             }

      // Send a report back and close the connection
            out.println("Server received " + numMessages + " messages"); 
      }

      catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally{
           try{
                System.out.println("!!!!! Closing connection... !!!!!\n" + "!!! Waiting for the next connection... !!!");
                link.close(); 
           }

           catch(IOException e){
                 System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
                System.exit(1);
           }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing into the program when you run it? Please show how you try to run it.

Comment: What exception was thrown? Printing your own message is not sufficient. You must print or log the actual exception.

Comment: I think it is working fine. In class the teacher likely had a program which then connected to the server socket but you don't seem to have any code posted which would act as a client and/or the client is not connecting to the right address/port.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. The problem is the code for the client. The answer to your problem is already written in a comment in your code.

```
    // Put the server into a waiting state
           link = servSock.accept();
```

The server goes into a waiting state until it gets a connection. The client is the one that would be getting the error since it did not connect. If the client was working correctly the code would continue and you would get the additional output.